# How to align 3 divs with CSS retaining relative position while scaling window

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS:

```
.div0{padding:5px;height:70px;}
.pos0{float:left;height:50px;padding:5px; background: red;}
.butt{float:middle; position:relative;top:8px;height:40px;}
.pos1 { background: green; position:relative;left:15px;top:4px;min-width:100px; }
.pos2 {  position:relative;left:15px;bottom:-8px;  } //background: yellow;
```

and this HTML:

```
<div class="div0" id="Div0" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 221);">

  <div class="pos0">
        <button name="Pag" class="butt" id="ButtFull0">MY butt here</button>
    </div>

   <div class="pos1"><span>  aLev:</span>
        <input size="1" id="S0" type="text"/><span>  vMin:</span>
        <input size="1" id="n0" type="text"/><span>  vMid:</span>
        <input size="1"  id="inp0" type="text" /><span>  vM:</span>
        <input size="1"  id="inp1" type="text"/><span id="Q0"> text</span>
    </div>

   <div class="pos2">
        <input id="y0" type="checkbox"/><span>  1°:</span>
        <input id="y10" type="checkbox"/><span>  2°:</span>
        <input id="e0" type="checkbox"/><span>  3°:</span>
        <input p id="p0" type="checkbox"/>
     </div>

</div>
```

I want the button vertically centered on the left and two lines with inputs and checkboxes at its right, both vertically even spaced. All maintaining position while shrinking the window.

I tried with this:
http://jsfiddle.net/qacp35fv/33/

Problems:

1) the 2 lines overlap the button (I put a background color green to better see the problem), so you can't easy click on it.

2) when shrinking the result window to the right, the 1° line becomes multiline: I prefer it remains one line without seeing some text and without increasing the total height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a good base to use. You can add your input elements in the correct divs.

```css
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0px;
    display: table;
}

#left-column {
    background: red;
    display: table-cell;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 120px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#right-column {
    background: yellow;
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: calc(100% - 120px);
    vertical-align: top;
}

#row-1, #row-2 {
    height: 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left-column">
        Left column
    </div>
    <div id="right-column">
        <div id="row-1">
            Right column row 1 with extra long text that will be hidden when resized.
        </div>
        <div id="row-2">
            Right column row 1
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This solves the first problem for the button. But it remains the second one of shrinking the page (to the right side) and getting multilines on the right column rows: I set your test at full page and reduced the window's width to the right.

Comment: Just added two additional rules to the CSS, it should work fine now.

Comment: Glad that I could help :-)

Comment: I have a problem: http://jsfiddle.net/kav7b3os/51/  a parent div has an override:hidden attr that hides the child divs. (I want to modify an existing page so I can't know if there is an existing overflow). Is there a way to bypass the parent overflow attr?